How to use the _api_disable_swagger_provider flag inside extraProperties? (use case: allow html answer instead of json for user email confirmation))
When you design an Api Platform application that allows user registration, you may need to display at least one HTML page when the user confirms her/his email address. That was not an easy thing if you want to handle this case inside the Api Platform application without using some sort of html proxy page. An issue was opened four years ago about it.
The problem was that Swagger intercepted the request and, as the browser typically send an Accept: text/html header (instead of the expected Accept: application/json), Swagger provided a 404 html error page.
Finally, this typical use case led Api Platform 3.3.8 to introduce the the new _api_disable_swagger_provider flag inside extraProperties. This flag is now used to prevent Swagger to intercept the request and allow the app to provide an html answer. Inspired by the test found in the commit, I tried to use it here :
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: 'UNIQ_IDENTIFIER_EMAIL', fields: ['email'])]
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(),
    new GetCollection(),
    new Post(),
    new Put(),
    new Patch(),
    new Delete(),
    new Get(
        name: 'user_activate',
        read: false,
        uriTemplate: '/users/activate/{token}',
        controller: ActivationController::class . '::activate',
        openapiContext: [
[...]
        ],
        extraProperties: [
            '_api_disable_swagger_provider' => true,
        ],
    ),
    new Post(
[...]
    ),
])]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
[...]

It does not work, I don't know why. I find no error any where, just a 404 response, from Swagger...
Anyone can help ?
I emptied the cache, restarted the server, asked the question on Github, look at all logs...
UPDATE: I made a GitHub repo with a nearly empty API Platform app that only contains the use case. Branches are tries to make the use case works (there are 2, both failed). Readme on each explain the problem, how to reproduce it, what was done to solve it, show the logs and the routes.
